# Show time value on recorded video in iPhone (Video Filtering)

Tags: ios, iphone, gpuimage, video-recording, avmutablecomposition

I am currently working on one application in which I am supposed to display the recording time while video recording is going on. Whats more interesting is that this recording time should also be there in the recorded video.

So I think I have two things to consider :
1.) Show recording time overlay while recording video
2.) Recording time should also be shown in the recorded video.

I know we can do the static text overlay while recording the video and then we add one text layer in recorded video. But in my case, this time value should be changed on every second.

I have searched a lot on google and stake overflow. Tried different solutions. By using GPUImage, By using AVMutableVideoComposition and CALayer. But they all are for static value.

May be I am nearer to my solution but not able to find it. So can anyone guide me on how can I achieve it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use AVAssetReader for recorded video. Get the CMSampleBufferRef, get it timestamp, draw time on sample buffer, write buffer to AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor. Similar approach for video being recorded.